# Facebook OpenGraph with PHP Variables - How to include unique OG info for each page

Tags: php, facebook, variables, facebook-opengraph

I hope someone can help me determine the best practice for the structure of my site.

Right now I have a header.php that is an include on all my pages.

This header includes the Facebook OpenGraph since it need to be between the  tags.

The thing is right now all my pages pull the same generic Facebook OG information while I want it to pull the specific info for each page. I am not sure how to do this. If I move the meta information off the header.php then it is not between the  tags.

It seems like using variables for each page would make sense but I am not sure how to have them load properly in the head.

How are people dealing with this issues of creating a template that deals with unique information on each page.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.png">

    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.militarypropertyproject.com/"/> 
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.militarypropertyproject.com/assets/img/facebook/facebook_og_image_mpp.jpg"/> 
    <meta property="og:description" content="Military Property Project is a top resource in managing your military living."/>
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
```

Comment: if you want page specific data to be loaded then you can only do this via a "common" file (header.php) if you pass the common file some indicator to tell it what specific data to load. Data should be loaded from a database or a folder structure relative to the page it is loaded from, and you can (probably) detect the page using a PHP `$_SERVER` variable.

Comment: Structure your application properly, so that it knows all values needed before it starts making the first output. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_model